# all Jexl objects in scripts return null on any method call

Tags: java, variables, jexl

I'm trying to get a jexl script to work.

```
// arranging namespace Print
Map<String, Object> ns = new HashMap<>(1);
ns.put("Print", System.out); // make System.out.println available in expressions
JexlEngine je = new JexlBuilder().namespaces(ns).create();

// arranging custom Map for accessible variable 'agent' in script
Map<String, Object> myMap = ....;
myMap.put("agent", agentRef);
JexlContext jc = new MapContext(myMap);

// arranging script
JexlScript script = je.createScript(expression);
Object result = script.execute(jc);
```

with the expression being this:

```
{
   Print:println("blabla");
   const x = agent.getId();
   Print:println(x);
   return true;
}
```

The first command just prints "blabla" to the console, so the printing via System.out.println works flawless.

However, for the variable agent: it does exist, because jexl doesn't report "unsolvable variable". However, any method of the agent Object which I try to call, always returns null.
I just get a null printed to the console.
When I debug, the agentRef does have values other than null on its fields, just before I put it in the Map. So the fields are NOT null.

Also, when I call agent.id (which should be possible, it is just a POJO), I get "undefined property 'id', assuming false". Whereas agent.getId() returns just null.

Anyone any idea what could go wrong here?

I tried other syntaxes, but to no avail. I tried using jc.set("agent", agentRef), but same result.

Comment: I do not know Jexl, but a quick scan of documentation suggest using `new JexlBuilder().permissions(JexlPermissions.UNRESTRICTED)...` (for testing only) and making sure the class of `agentRef` and respective members are `public`

Comment: Just tested it, I can confirm previous comment (also `agent.id` ends up calling the `getId()`, as long as the method is `public`)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The class of agentRef and its getId() method is indeed public, so that is not the problem. However, your UNRESTRICTED permissions did solve the problem. So many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JexlPermissions.UNRESTRICTED:

```
JexlEngine jexl = new JexlBuilder().features(features)
                .permissions(JexlPermissions.UNRESTRICTED).create();
```

If you are using Java 17 or later, you need to 'expose' the object to the script as well. Your module should contain a module-info.java file. If the namespace of the class is 'com.foo' then the module-info.java file should contain something like this:

```
module <name of your module> {
    opens com.foo;
}
```

If you do not do this, Jexl will not be able to see the method using Reflection. No error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

JEXL will only see/introspect public classes for which it is allowed to through permissions; your own classes/packages must be allowed (they aren't by default) and they must be public.
To learn how to create proper permissions and to avoid using JexlPermissions.UNRESTRICTED in production, see [JexlPermissions](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jexl3/introspection/JexlPermissions.html)